# Should the preposition "on" be used again in this sentence?

Tags: prepositions, parallelism

Notice the following:

> I wondered if my going to this different place was as hard on him as it **was me**.

I remember being taught to occasionally repeat certain words in order to preserve parallelism. Should there be an additional *on* between *was* and *me* here, or is the meaning the same regardless? Thanks!

Comment: I would certainly use _as it was on me_.

Comment: It's better to repeat the preposition here, but it's not uncommon to omit it.

Comment: Thank you, @KateBunting and @Barmar!